# breaking a row of datatable into multiple row with serverside method

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

I have a mysql table that store all info about customer supports like smsPanel,website,vmodule,.....

```
customerName|smspanel|SMSstartDay|SMSexpDay |websit|WebStartDay|webExpDay|
------------------------------------------------------------
john        |yes     |2019/01/15 |2020/01/15|yes   |2019/02/12 |2020/02/12
```

I am using datatable serverside method to show informations. Its ok when I show every single row of database in single row of data table. but i want to show every support package in different row lik this

```
customerName  |  package | StartDay  | EndDate
----------------------------------------------
jhon          | SMS      |2019/01/15 |2020/01/15
jhon          | website  |2019/02/12 |2020/02/12
```

this is my sql query for datatable serverSide

```
if($ssaction == "customerSupportlist"){
$table = <<<EOT
 (
    SELECT
    *
    FROM pdsupport
    where customer_smsPack >0
 ) temp
EOT;
}
```

and i use this cod to format datatable but its useful for one row display

```
if($ssaction == "customerSupportlist"){
    $primaryKey='id';

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'customer_fname','dt' => 0),
    array( 'db' => 'customer_lname',  'dt' => 1 ),


    array('db' => 'customer_ncode','dt' => 2),
    array('db' => 'customer_mobile','dt' => 3),  
     array( 'db' => 'id',
          'dt' => 4,
            'formatter' =>function( $d, $row ) {
            $customerPacks=getCustomerPacks($d);
           return   $customerPacks;
        }

           ),    
         array( 'db' => 'id',
          'dt' => 5,
            'formatter' =>function( $d, $row ) {
            $startDate=getCustomerPackStartDate($d);
           return   $startDate;
        }

           ),
     array( 'db' => 'id',
          'dt' => 6,
            'formatter' =>function( $d, $row ) {
            $endDate=getCustomerPackEndDate($d);
           return   $endDate;
        }

           ),
      array( 'db' => 'id','dt' => 7 ),


);
}
```

I dont know how to modify this part to split the rows. OR by changing mysql query make a table that has my favorite structure